# is there a way to apply data augmentation on a numpy array of images?

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, data-augmentation

I was wondering if it's possible to apply data augmentation on my NumPy array of images instead of using it with the help of image data generator
I'm currently working on Keras framework

Comment: Why exactly can't you use Keras's `ImageDataGenerator`?

Comment: i am trying to apply MTCNN detection before feeding it to the network, is there a way to go around that?